# Xuggler: extract a thumbnail of a given frame from a video

Tags: java, xuggler

I have an mp4 video and I have to extract a thumbnail image of a specific frame from the video using java xuggler.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/artclarke/xuggle-xuggler/tree/master/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos
Have a look at the "DecodeAndCaptureFrames.java" that might help.

It worked for me until I got fatals error (EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)) while doing:
 if (container.open(filename, IContainer.Type.READ, null) < 0)